# Ocean modifier value cant be keyframed

Tags: modifiers, keyframes, ocean-simulation

I'm trying to animate the ocean modifier and I really want to use the direction value. For some reason It does not seem like it can be keyframed, is there any way to keyframe the value or a workaround? Using 2.81

[image]

Comment: you can use drivers for any slider you have just make an empty and assign a driver for the slider to the empty position. here is a quick tut: https://youtu.be/5SdKAUsjcsg

Comment: @Mobin This property specifically can't be animated, I don't think it is possible to unless you are willing to dive into blender's source code and change the property definition. But anyway I think they set it as non-animatable for a reason so you won't be able to unfortunately.

Comment: Damn, this is probably the best way I've found to loop the ocean modifier